# How can I read odd and even lines for coordinates in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, coordinates

During his completely miserable life, pirate Abraham Blaufelt has been in search
of the lost treasure of Atlantis. On a very fortunate day in the year of the Lord
1642 he enters an abandoned cathedral of a long gone sect in the ancient forests
of Poland. Inside he finds a mysterious ancient parchment. The parchment
reads:

Traveler, if you want to reach thine goal,
trace the path through seas by making the broken, whole.

5,4 4,5 8,7

Add behind 6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3

Add in front 7,6

Add behind 9,8

Add in front 5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4

Abraham Blaufelt immediately knew what he was dealing with. A puzzle of
which the result is a safe route to the treasure. This route was essential, the
sea was crawling with monsters in those days. Since this most fortunate day,
almost four hundred years ago, the european tectonic plate has shifted significantly.
As a result all coordinates have to be shifted by (1; 0).
Write a program that solves this puzzle. This has to be done in the following
way: Start with the coordinates on the first row, add the coordinates of the
second row at the back, then add the coordinates of the third row in front etc.
Make a new Coordinate and CoordinateRow class for this assignment. The
latter class has methods to add a CoordinateRow in front or at the back and
methods to add a single Coordinate at the front or at the back.
The coordinates of the puzzle are in a file on Blackboard. Every CoordinateRow
is separated from another by an ’=’. Every coordinate in a row is separated by
a space. The x and y values of a coordinate are separated by a comma.
After all data has been read, the program will print the treasure route on the
standard output.

Input text:

5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4t

Currently, I seem only able to get 5,4 coordinate only. There is something weird that I cannot read other coordinates. I guess it is probably something to do with reading the even and odd lines? Please help...

```
package module5;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

public class Pirate1 {
    PrintStream out;

    CoordinateRow coordinateArray = new CoordinateRow();
    CoordinateRow frontArray = new CoordinateRow();

    Pirate1() {
        out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    }   


    void processAll(Scanner fileScanner) {
        fileScanner.useDelimiter("=");
        int counter = 0;
        String coordinateGroup = " ";
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            if (counter == 0 || counter % 2 != 0) {
                coordinateGroup = fileScanner.next();
                getCoordinates(coordinateGroup);
            } else if (counter %2 == 0) {
                coordinateGroup = fileScanner.next();
                getCoordinatesFront(coordinateGroup);
            }
        }

    }

    void getCoordinates(String coordinateGroup) {
        Scanner secondScanner = new Scanner(coordinateGroup);
        String individualCoordinates = " ";
        while (secondScanner.hasNext()) {
            Coordinate c = new Coordinate();
            individualCoordinates = secondScanner.next();
            c = getIndividual (individualCoordinates);
            coordinateArray.addCoordinate(c);       
            }

    }

    void getCoordinatesFront(String coordinateGroup) {
        out.print("test Coordinate");
        Scanner secondScanner = new Scanner (coordinateGroup);
        String individualCoordinates = " ";

            if (frontArray.numberOfElements == 0) {
                Coordinate c = new Coordinate();
                c = getIndividual (coordinateGroup);
                frontArray.addCoordinate(c);
                out.print(frontArray.coordinateRow[0].x + ", " + frontArray.coordinateRow[0].y );

        } else {
            Scanner individualCoordinateScanner = new Scanner(coordinateGroup);
            CoordinateRow temp = new CoordinateRow();
            while(individualCoordinateScanner.hasNext()) {
                Coordinate c = new Coordinate();
                c.x =individualCoordinateScanner.nextInt();
                c.y = individualCoordinateScanner.nextInt();
                temp.addCoordinate(c);
            }

        for (int i= temp.numberOfElements; i > 0; i--) {
            frontArray.shiftAndPlaceCoordinate(temp.coordinateRow[i]);
            } 

    }
}


    Coordinate getIndividual(String individualCoordinateline) {
        Scanner individualCoordinateScanner = new Scanner(individualCoordinateline);
        individualCoordinateScanner.useDelimiter(",");
        Coordinate individualCoordinates = new Coordinate();
        while (individualCoordinateScanner.hasNext()) {
            individualCoordinates.x = individualCoordinateScanner.nextInt();
            individualCoordinates.y = individualCoordinateScanner.nextInt();


        }
    return individualCoordinates;
    }


    void start() {
        Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
        processAll(fileScanner);
        out.print(coordinateArray.coordinateRow[0].x + " " + coordinateArray.coordinateRow[0].y );
        //out.print(frontArray.coordinateRow[0].x + " " + frontArray.coordinateRow[0].y );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Pirate1().start();

    }
}
```

```
class CoordinateRow {
    static final int MAX_SIZE = 20;
    Coordinate [] coordinateRow; 
    int numberOfElements;

    CoordinateRow () {
        coordinateRow = new Coordinate [MAX_SIZE];
        numberOfElements = 0;
    }   

    void addCoordinate (Coordinate coord) {
        coordinateRow [numberOfElements] = coord;
        numberOfElements = +1;
    }

    void shiftAndPlaceCoordinate (Coordinate coord) { 
        if(numberOfElements > MAX_SIZE) {
            for(int i= numberOfElements +1; i> 0; --i) {
                this.coordinateRow[i]= this.coordinateRow[i-1];
            }
            numberOfElements += 1;
            this.coordinateRow[0] = coord;
        }
    }

}
```

```
package module5;

public class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y; 
    Coordinate () {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    Coordinate (int x, int y){
        this.x = x + 1;
        this.y = y;
    }


}
```